# Using input filter for an edittext in android

Tags: java, android

I am using an input filter for an edittext for which i have the following requirements:

1)The first character should NOT be a digit
2) From the second character onwards letters,digits,underscore and dot is allowed

I got the following code from a post:

```
filter_username = new InputFilter() { 
         public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                boolean keepOriginal = true;
                 sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

                    char c = source.charAt(i);
//                  testString.append(c);
                    if (isCharAllowed2(c)) // put your condition here
                        sb.append(c);
                    else
                        keepOriginal = false;
                }
                if (keepOriginal)
                    return null;
                else {
                    if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                        SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                        TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                        return sp;
                    } else {
                        return sb;
                    }           
                }
            }

            private boolean isCharAllowed2(char c) {
                if(sb.length()==0)
                {
                      return Character.isLetter(c);
                }
                else
                {
                return (Character.isLetter(c)||Character.isDigit(c)||c=='_'||c=='.');
                }

            }

};
```

I am only able to type letters.The problem i think is this line:

```
sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
```

Each time i press the key , a new Stringbuilder object would be created.So the length of it would be zero and the first condition for letters only would be returned.

So i thought of setting the stringbuilder into another variable.It worked partially but when i press backspace and clear the text,that new variable's value also has to be cleared.How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using textwatcher to validate inputs

TextWatcher's method `afterTextChanged` will be called everytime after user enters or deletes a character. You can validate the inputs based (given in code) and then show a error if user enters a invalid character.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text = edittext.getText().toString();
            String len = text.length();

            if(Character.isDigit(text.charAt(0))){
                //First letter is a digit. Do something
                //Show an error
            }

            text.substring(1); //remove first character from string

            if(text.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$"){
                //contains invalid character (listed by you)
                //it contains a character among a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ or .
                //show an error
            }

        }
    });
```

So if you find any invalid character, you can show an error to the user and prevent him from continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `InputFilter` is explained in the docs:

> This method is called when the buffer is going to replace the range dstart … dend of dest with the new text from the range start … end of source. Return the CharSequence that you would like to have placed there instead, including an empty string if appropriate, or null to accept the original replacement. Be careful to not to reject 0-length replacements, as this is what happens when you delete text. Also beware that you should not attempt to make any changes to dest from this method; you may only examine it for context. Note: If source is an instance of Spanned or Spannable, the span objects in the source should be copied into the filtered result (i.e. the non-null return value). copySpansFrom(Spanned, int, int, Class, Spannable, int) can be used for convenience.

So, Just return `""` to block unwanted characters:

```
public class MyTextFilter implements InputFilter {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, Spanned spanned, int i3, int i4) {

        // delete support
        if(charSequence.length() < 1){
            return null;
        }

        // allow only if replacement has valid pattern.
        if (i3 == 0) {
            return charSequence.toString().matches("\\d[\\w\\._\\d]?") ? null : "";
        } else {
            return charSequence.toString().matches("[\\w\\._\\d]?") ? null : "";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, above API 19, you can use `Character.isAlphabetic()` method.